# How to create a 30 day countdown in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, saas

I'm trying to create an app that has a 30 day free trial in Laravel. The day starts counting from the moment he user registers. I've been trying to figure out a way to code but I keep coming up with nothing.

If anyone can help me out, I'll really appreciate it. My laravel app version is 5.7 and my PHP version is 7.1.

Edit: I must say I'm relatively new to laravel so this question may seem a bit weird

Comment: Have you tried anything your self? If not, then please do so first, otherwise, please show us some of the code you've been trying out. :)

Comment: You don't really have to countdown at all. You can just store the user sign up date and whenever the user is back, use maths to figure out if 30 days have passed since the user signed up.

Comment: Djip, yes I have. I followed this https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-saas-free-trial-implementation/ but it isn't working for me. I don't know why

Comment: Josephting, can you help me out with a rough code?

Comment: You should be on your way just by following the tutorial you linked. There are too many ways to implement this. In the tutorial, a field that stores the free trial expiry date into the database is used instead, which works too.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it should have worked initially too. But then I check my database and found that the field that store the free trial expiry is null for all the users. And that's the reason why it isn't working for me. If there's another way to implement it, I'd really appreciate.

Comment: The `trial_until` field will only get stored when user register new account or when a new user account is created.

Comment: I have created and registered a new user several times and the trial_until field does not get stored.

Comment: I have finally gotten it to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use `created_at` too

Comment: you can use `created_at` column but it`s better create new column name as `expired_at`. You can manipulate it under middleware or task scheduler..